# Execute command when buffer is in directory in vim

Tags: vim, macvim

I am searching a way to execute a command(:term) when buffer is pointing to a directory(like NERDTree gets opened when opening vim pointing to a dir)
and when buffer is empty/start screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plugins like NERDTree use so called *scratch buffers* to display their "UI". For syntax highlighting, most also set a custom, plugin-specific *filetype*. So you can hook into the [`:help FileType`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#FileType) event: `:autocmd FileType nerdtree ...`

Directly opening the terminal didn't work for me; as the plugin is interrupted inside its scratch buffer setup, and doesn't expect the terminal to interfere. At least additional commands to return to the original scratch buffer would be needed here. (But something inconspicuous like `:echomsg` would work as-is.) Or you just delay the opening via [`feedkeys()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#feedkeys%28%29):

```
:autocmd FileType nerdtree call feedkeys(":terminal\<CR>")
```

A more generic approach (that would work not just for NERDTree) could hook into `BufWinEnter` and check whether `&buftype == 'nofile'` (which is a typical attribute of scratch buffers).

To check whether Vim starts up with the "start screen", use [`VimEnter`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#VimEnter) and check that `empty(bufname(''))`.

```
:autocmd VimEnter * if empty(bufname('')) | exe "terminal" | endif
```

Comment: when running ```:autocmd FileType nerdtree call feedkeys(":terminal\<CR>")``` im getting the terminal opened but im also getting the :terminal command in the terminal

Comment: could you give an example for the BufWinEnter and VimEnter?

Comment: Okay, I put one that opens the terminal if no files have been passed to Vim on startup. It should have been pretty straightforward already. If you don't fully understand this, I would advise against blindly copying these to your `.vimrc`. As these customizations accumulate, side effects may happen, and it'll cause you a hard time troubleshooting this.